# React with a handler function that returns a function (a curried) - what's the benefit of using it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks

I'm writing a component that renders `Checkboxes` of `Categories` as part of a large system, here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Checkbox = ({ categories, handleFilter }) => {

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

    // get all the categories that user clicked and send them to the Backend
    const handleToggle = c => () => {
        const currentCategoryId = checked.indexOf(c); // return the first index with cateogry 'c
        const newCheckedCategoryId = [...checked];

        // if currently checked wasn't already in Checked state ==> Push
        // else Pull it

        // User want to Check
        if (currentCategoryId === -1) {
            // not in the state
            newCheckedCategoryId.push(c);
        }
        else {
            // User wants to Uncheck
            newCheckedCategoryId.splice(currentCategoryId, 1); // remove it from the array
        }
        // console.log(newCheckedCategoryId);
        setChecked(newCheckedCategoryId);
        handleFilter(newCheckedCategoryId, 'category');
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
                categories.map((cat, index) => (
                    <li key={index} className='list-unstyled'>
                        <input
                            onChange={handleToggle(cat._id)}
                            value={checked.indexOf(cat._id) === -1}
                            type='checkbox'
                            className='form-check-input' />
                        <label className='form-check-label'>{cat.name}</label>
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </>

    )
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Whenever a user clicks one of the `Checkboxes` the handler `handleToggle` is invoked.

What I don't understand is why I need to use a curried function?

When I try to use:

```
const handleToggle = c => { ... }
```

Instead of:

```
const handleToggle = c => () => { ... }
```

React throws:

```
 Unhandled Rejection (Error): Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

What's the deal here and why is it required to use a curried function ?

Comment: onChange requires a callback instead of a function call.

Comment: `handleToggle` here is really a *handler factory*, which is why you're *calling* it to get a handler to supply as `onChange`. If you make it just a handler itself without changing how it's used, it gets called every time the component renders, not just when when the change event happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is `handleToggle` has been evaluated and assigned the result of that function to `onChange` instead of passing as a callback function.

Based on that you need to change how you call the function `handleToggle` as:

```
onChange={() => handleToggle(cat._id)}
```

From your example:

```
onChange={handleToggle(cat._id)}
```

And at the end `const handleToggle = c => { ... }` will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to your `onChange` function you are calling function directly instead of assigning it:

```
onChange={handleToggle(cat._id)} <- Call as soon as this sees
```

instead you have to do this:

```
onChange={() => handleToggle(cat._id)}
```

And define `handleToggle` like this:

```
// get all the categories that user clicked and send them to the Backend
    const handleToggle = c => {
        const currentCategoryId = checked.indexOf(c); // return the first index with cateogry 'c
        const newCheckedCategoryId = [...checked];

        // if currently checked wasn't already in Checked state ==> Push
        // else Pull it

        // User want to Check
        if (currentCategoryId === -1) {
            // not in the state
            newCheckedCategoryId.push(c);
        }
        else {
            // User wants to Uncheck
            newCheckedCategoryId.splice(currentCategoryId, 1); // remove it from the array
        }
        // console.log(newCheckedCategoryId);
        setChecked(newCheckedCategoryId);
        handleFilter(newCheckedCategoryId, 'category');
    }
```